# Connect Microsoft Account to Domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-10, user-accounts

I'd like to link a standard domain account to a Microsoft Account on Windows 10 v1607. Typically, one would go to Settings / Accounts / Your info, but the option is not shown. I've disabled the GPO to block Microsoft Accounts, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 2):

So you need to sync to a Microsoft account via Cortana (https://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-10-insider-preview/359824-connecting-domain-account-microsoft-account.html)

You need to activate Cortana and you can choose to sync then. I don't think this is possible via GPO but as an individual (assuming Cortana is enabled) then you should be able to do it. Hope this helps!

Comment: The post linked also states you should be able to link via onedrive too

Comment: I saw this, but the option to sync settings is still greyed out in "Settings / Accounts /  Sync your settings". It says the features are only available when using a Microsoft account or work account.

Comment: Is the account on the machine a local account rather than a domain account then?

Comment: It's a domain account. The local accounts have no issue.

Comment: I have a standard domain rather than an azure domain that I can test with but I wonder if it would work on an azure domain. My thinking is that an azure domain account would already be a microsoft account.

Comment: From what I was reading when searching, Azure domains should allow logging in with MS accounts.